# devise_token_auth - No access-token in response headers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am using devise_token_auth, Ver 0.1.37, in my rails application. I am using rspec to test my application.

The sign-in to application is successful and access-token is returned in response header. On subsequent request, the new access token is not received. The request was successful with a HTTP status 201.

Comment: Here is the sample request header sent out after sign-in.

`{"ACCEPT"=>"application/json",
 "Content-Type"=>"application/json",
 "access-token"=>"SYotATXiRVWJbkX_LR2TLw",
 "token-type"=>"Bearer",
 "client"=>"188dmqOWOLsAAzFVBD1vJg",
 "expiry"=>"1456358941",
 "uid"=>"vida@kihn.net"}`

Comment: Maybe its because of batch requests when token is not updated?

Answer (score 1):

I was beating my head against the wall with this issue for some time, and solved it in my React Native project by:

- ensuring I was whitelisting the headers in my rails app (in the Rack CORS config file)

  `config.middleware.insert_before 'Rack::Runtime', 'Rack::Cors' do
    allow do
      origins '*'
      resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      expose: ['access-token', 'expiry', 'token-type', 'uid', 'client'],
      methods: [:get, :put, :post, :patch, :delete, :options]
    end
  end`
- saving (with AsynStorage) the auth headers I got back after logging in

  `if (resp.ok) {
      if (resp.headers.get('access-token')) {
        let accessToken = resp.headers.get('access-token');
        let client      = resp.headers.get('client');
        let expiry      = resp.headers.get('expiry');
        let tokenType   = resp.headers.get('token-type');
        let uid         = resp.headers.get('uid');
        let authHeader  = {'client': client, expiry: expiry, uid: uid, 'access-token': accessToken, 'token-type': tokenType};
        AsyncStorage.setItem('auth_header', JSON.stringify(authHeader));
      }
      return json;
   }`
- using the saved headers for each subsequent requests

  `export function fetchTheThing() {
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
      return AsyncStorage.getItem('auth_header', (err, result) => {
        return Api.get(`/the_thing`, null, result).then(resp => {
          dispatch(setFetchedThing({ thing: resp }));
        }).catch((ex) => {
          console.log(ex);
        });
      });
    };
  }`

I was also running into issue with the default setting that resets the token each request, so I set that to false in the devise_token_auth.rb.

(sorry for the formatting of those code blocks)